# jquery mobile device orientation change not resizing text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to figure out a way to resize a text area using JQM when the device rotates.  Basically, I have a text area that looks good when it loads, whether in portrait or landscape, but when the device is rotated, it does not resize.  Here is a bit of what the code looks like:

```
.message-entry{
   margin-left:10px;
   margin-right:0;
   margin-bottom:-20px;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
 <footer data-role="footer" id="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed">               
            <label class="label-message-entry" for="chatMessageEntry">Enter a message:</label>
            <textarea rows="8" name="textarea" class="message-entry" id="chatMessageEntry"></textarea>
            <a id="chatReplyButton" class="reply-button" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Reply</a>              
        </footer> <!--end footer-->
```

and then the orientationchange event:

```
$(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
        var newWidth = $(window).width();
        $('.message-entry').css({'width':newWidth + 'px'});     
});
```

any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried giving the textarea a min-width within a media query?

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 321px){
    .message-entry{
        min-width:470px;
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 320px){
    .message-entry{
        min-width:310px;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is that syntax?  I am just doing this right in the browser using JS, HTML, and CSS

Comment: But also, what about iPads and things?  The device sizes are never going to be constant, so you can't hardcode min/max widths...

Comment: Ok, do you have a live version of your problem to test?